# Checking if an array is sorted (increasing, strictly increasing, decreasing, strictly decreasing) in javascript most efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

I know how to do it (in terms of simple implementation), but I want a way to do it "most efficiently" and with "min. amount of code" (for a minimal js library) without any other dependencies.

Expected behaviour and details (sign optional):

```
function isSorted(array, sign) {
    // code
}

console.log(isSorted([1,2,2,4]));
// true: default behaviour (non-decreasing or increasing; sign : '>=')

console.log(isSorted([4,3,2,1], '<'));
// true : strictly decreasing

console.log(isSorted([4,3,3,1], '<='));
// true : decreasing
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, sorry for any misunderstanding, I mean, I know how to do it in terms of naive implementation, which may not be that short and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object for the comparison callbacks and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with short circuit if returning `false`.

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `every`, it will be passed to `callback` when invoked, for use as its `this` value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value.  The `this` value ultimately observable by `callback` is determined according to the usual rules for determining the `this` seen by a function.

```js
function isSorted(array, sign) {
    var compare = {
        '<': function (a, b) { return a < b; },
        '>': function (a, b) { return a > b; },
        '<=': function (a, b) { return a <= b; },
        '>=': function (a, b) { return a >= b; },
    };
    return array.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return !i || this(a, aa[i - 1]);
    }, compare[sign] || compare['>=']);
}

console.log(isSorted([1, 2, 2, 4]));           // true default behaviour (non-decreasing or increasing; sign : '>=')
console.log(isSorted([4, 3, 2, 1], '<'));      // true strictly decreasing
console.log(isSorted([4, 3, 3, 1], '<='));     // true decreasing
console.log(isSorted([1, 2, 42, 2, 4]));       // false
console.log(isSorted([4, 3, 42, 2, 1], '<'));  // false
console.log(isSorted([4, 3, 42, 3, 1], '<=')); // false
```

Comment: Just a minor question, does the value `compare[sign] || compare['>=']`gets evaluated for each iteration.?
Cause if thats the case we can store it in a variable to make it more efficient.

Comment: it just once evaluated and inside accessed with `this`.